# Can Cordova deprecation warnings make Apple reject our app?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, appstore-approval

Our app uses the `Ionic Framework` with `Cordova` (5.4.0), but when we build it and run it through Xcode we get multiple deprecation warnings saying `Deprecated in Cordova 3.9.2. (...) This will be removed in 4.0.0.`

Shouldn't these be removed by now and can this possibly make our app rejected when submitting to App Store?

Comment: No idea, that's why I asked the question. I'm not too familiar on Apples app guidelines and I can't find any clear information on this.

Comment: I don't think you are thinking it through too well.  Cordova is a 3rd party library, and make decisions about what gets deprecated and when in their codebase.  It's irrelevant to Apple who only care about how you use their API.

Comment: The issue is not that I'm not thinking it through, the issue is I don't know on what level Apple reviews my app. Your last line was a proper answer, but by the time you posted it I had already gotten 2 answers saying the same thing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this will not result in app rejection. Apple are concerned about usage of their private APIs, but wouldn't even reject an app due to deprecation warnings from Apple libraries.

In short, deprecation warnings are there to warn the developer that an API call they're using might disappear soon, and that upgrading to a new version of the library will require rewriting code. This has no effect on already-built apps.

Further, it would be a great deal of work for them to figure out if you were using deprecated APIs from third-party libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Apple will not reject your app. Deprecated frameworks have no bearing on Apple's decisions. These warning are purely from Cordova to let you know that the methods you are using are likely to be removed. Along as you can compile your code and generate a stable working app, Apple will not care.

In some case you have to use some of Apple's deprecated API's. This is for situations when you are targeting an older platform than the one that the framework was deprecated in.

I would also put a comment in your code to remind yourself why you are using a deprecated API. If you cannot think of anything to write, then you really should be using the new API to ensure your app stay future proof.